# How is average character width calculated

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, character

According to the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-textarea-cols), *The cols attribute specifies the expected maximum number of characters per line.*

This is true when the font used has the same width for every character.

According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_cols.asp), *The cols attribute pecifies the width of the text area (in average character width).*

My guess is that they mean the font's average character width and not the average character width of the text in the textarea.

Now my question is how does the user agent calculate the **average character width** for a certain font, what characters are included in this calculation, ... Is there a way I can get this information or calculate it myself?

What I want to do: calculate the **visual** number of lines inside a textarea witheout using anything else except the textContent and the cols attribute.

What I already tried:

- Calculate the average character width of the textContent:

```js
const textSpan = document.getElementById("textSpan");
const textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

textarea.addEventListener("input", (evt) => {
  textSpan.innerText = evt.target.value;
  console.log("Predicted number of lines: " + (textSpan.getBoundingClientRect().width / (textSpan.getBoundingClientRect().width / textSpan.innerText.length * 10))) // 10 = cols attribute of textarea element;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" cols="10" rows="10" style="word-break: break-all;"></textarea>
<span id="textSpan"></span>
```

- Calculate the average character width of most characters, this may work but I have to know what characters to use for the calculation...:

```js
const textSpan = document.getElementById("textSpan");
const textSpanACW = document.getElementById("textSpanACW");
const textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

textarea.addEventListener("input", (evt) => {
  textSpan.innerText = evt.target.value;
  console.log("Predicted number of lines: " + (textSpan.getBoundingClientRect().width / (textSpanACW.getBoundingClientRect().width / textSpanACW.innerText.length * 10))) // 10 = cols attribute of textarea element;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" cols="10" rows="10" style="word-break: break-all;"></textarea>
<span id="textSpanACW">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ,;?.:/=+ù%µ£^¨$*-_)àç!è§('"é&|@#¼½^{[{}</span>
<span id="textSpan"></span>
```

Once I have figured this out I have to get the number of visual lines without using `word-break: break-all;`. So that would be nice to have in the answer but not needed.

Comment: it be easier to compare textarea'width to span's width and calculate from that difference. set the same font-family for both.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Great suggestion, will try that out. But I am still interested in an answer to this question. Thank you!

Comment: possible example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWbpJyB?editors=1111 . border/padding/font rules and eventually the scrollbar showing up is to think of .

Comment: for the character's width , you have the mono-space font where each character is the same and the others depending on the size of each. browser print them at screen but do not make any calculation, you need to retrieve their total lenght once printed :( You can only count them and mind the white-space too. )

Comment: @G-Cyrillus The snippet doesn't work accurate enough. Yes I know about those fonts but don't want to use them. I also know I have to calculate it but how is the question and what characters to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading further in the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/rendering.html#ref-for-textarea-effective-width): *The textarea effective width of a textarea element is size×avg + sbw, where size is the element’s character width, avg is the average character width of the primary font of the element, in CSS pixels, and sbw is the width of a scroll bar, in CSS pixels. (The element’s letter-spacing property does not affect the result.)*.

So the formula for calculating **average character width (avg)** is: `(effectiveWidth - sbw) / size`.

Getting **sbw**:

```
<style>
    /* way the hell off screen */
    .scrollbar-measure {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: scroll;
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    const sbw = getScrollbarWidth();

    function getScrollbarWidth() {
        let scrollDiv = document.createElement("div");
        scrollDiv.className = "scrollbar-measure";
        document.body.appendChild(scrollDiv);
        const scrollbarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth;
        document.body.removeChild(scrollDiv);
        return scrollbarWidth;
    }

</script>
```

Getting **size**:

In the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#character-width): *The cols attribute specifies the expected maximum number of characters per line. If the cols attribute is specified, its value must be a valid non-negative integer greater than zero. If applying the rules for parsing non-negative integers to the attribute’s value results in a number greater than zero, then the element’s character width is that value; otherwise, it is 20.*

So:

```
let size = parseInt(textarea.getAttribute("cols"));

if (isNaN(size)) {
    size = 20;
}
```

Getting **effective width**:

*If the element has a cols attribute, and parsing that attribute’s value using the rules for parsing non-negative integers doesn’t generate an error, then the user agent is expected to use the attribute as a presentational hint for the width property on the element, with the value being the textarea effective width (as defined below). Otherwise, the user agent is expected to act as if it had a user-agent-level style sheet rule setting the width property on the element to the textarea effective width.*

So:

```
const effectiveWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(textarea).getPropertyValue("width").slice(0, -2));
```